# Font Awesome Icons showing in Chinese on LG G3

Tags: font-awesome

We are using font awesome on our site www.greenteamservicecorp.com. The fonts show upon all browsers (tested chrome, firefox, and IE) on PC. They also work on galaxy s6 mobile. But on the LG G3 they are showing up as Chinese symbols. We have not had a chance to check iOS yet. But as for LG, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using them incorrectly. Not sure if this is why they're not showing on the LG, but the code is wrong.

```
<i class="fa fa-fa-phone fa-phone " ></i>
```

should be

```
<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
```

---

```
<i class="fa fa-fa-envelope-o fa-envelope-o ">
```

should be

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope-o">
```

etc...

Comment: I also checked and they're showing on an iPhone. However, you have other issues to worry about - the layout is messed up.

Comment: The code used on the backend of the site is [icon name="fa-wrench"]. The preliminary template utilized the icon in this manner. I do not see anywhere the double entry you noted?

Comment: Also, can you screen shot how the layout is messed up? The only thing we have noticed odd on mobile so far is the slide show text being too tiny.

Comment: Regardless of the snippets in your CMS, go to the site and look at the source code in a browser; you will see the font awesome code is incorrect. The iPhone layout has a large white margin on the right side. You can't miss it.

Comment: Tim, I just checked the source code and I see what you mean. But this is my first time using FA Icons. I am not sure where/how to correct this? It is not showing double in the back end editor. Also, thank you we will find an iphone to test with and fix.

Comment: You'll have to look into the proper way to enter the icon code in the editor, as their could be many ways to do this. Off the top of my head, it looks like you might be using Wordpress? Try `[icon name="wrench"]`

Comment: We are using joomla. So try removing the fa?

Comment: I honestly have no idea - it's probably different for every system and plugin.  Can't hurt to try it and see what happens :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will see what happens. If not, I have a ticket in to the builder as well.

Comment: Great! if this solved the problem, don't forget to mark this question as solved so other people won't try to answer it.

Comment: Tim, thanks for the try, but it didn't work. Hopefully the creator will get back to me or someone else may have an answer. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: please let me know what the issue is when you find out!